# call text file with words and numbers into arrays in a single function prototype

Tags: c

I aimed to read text file such as

**File**:

```
1 2 93  35  I_have_no_idea
2 4 5 45 I_dont_care
```

I want to read in into arrays (5 arrays)

**Code**:

```
int read_data(int id[], double year[], double earning[], double budget[], char name[]){
    int i, nmovies;
    int ch;
    if ((ch = getchar())==EOF){
        return -1;
    }
    for (i=0; scanf("%d", id+i)==1 && scanf("%d", id+i) != EOF ; i++){
        while(fscanf(
        scanf( "%lf %lf %lf %s\n", year+i, earning+i, budget+i, name+i);
    }
    nmovies = i;
    return nmovies;
}
```

But it just giving me single id value.

What is wrong and how this should be changed?

Comment: This doesn't look like c# code.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a class of this, not a method. (a dictionary is also an option, but i wouldnt recommend it)

after that you should make a new instance of the class for every line in the text file. you can put those in a list or an array of the class

(FYI if you want to keep using it like this, then you should at least make the `char name[]` a `string name[]`)

edit:
if this is in C then you can discard the above, because then you dont have classes. If its c++ then do use it as above in a class

Answer (score 0):

in the condition of your for loop, `scanf("%d", id+i)==1 && scanf("%d", id+i) != EOF`, you call `scanf` twice. Since `i` has not yet been incremented, the second call will overwrite the result of the first call.

Further, `scanf` returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned. It does not return `EOF`.